# Print the values of the count in the Text box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have taken the count size in the print in the console , can't able to enter the size in the website

This is my code 
driver.get("http://suvian.in/selenium/2.6liCount.html");

```
    List<WebElement> book=driver.findElementsByXPath("//ul[@id='books']/li");
    List<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(WebElement listtable:book)
    {
        text.add(listtable.getText());
    }
    System.out.println(text.size());
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

This is the website of the code http://suvian.in/selenium/2.6liCount.html

Comment: Can you be clear what you want to do

Comment: I need to print the values of all the books in the textbox ,which I can't able to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to input total count of chapters in all book

```
List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='books']/li/ul/li");

System.out.print(ele.size);

driver.findElement(By.Id("chapall")).sendKeys(ele.size);
```